# Can't embed certain youtube videos into theme

Tags: themes, embed, youtube

I am unable to successfully embed (certain) YouTube URLs into my theme in the back end, with the intention of having viewable video clips on the front end. Not sure if this a WordPress issue or an issue with the video URLs themselves. I am using Divi, but have confirmed the problem is the same with Gutenberg and the Twenty Twenty theme.

All videos in question play fine on YouTube itself.

If I choose a random trending video from YouTube, the embed works fine. If I use one of my client's videos, nothing shows up on the front end.

Example probem video from my client:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rLZhyfkgHvs

Example working video, a random video chosem from youTube:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B3MDJsggfDg

Any ideas what might be going on?

**EDIT: Note that the issue is only for client-created videos. Random YouTube videos embed and play fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had recently similar issue with Divi and embedding videos. At the end I realized its because oEmbed issues in WordPress sites running on host with both IPv4 and IPv6 sites.

Either you can add this code to your functions.php to fix this:

```
add_action( 'http_api_curl', function( $curl_handle ) {
   curl_setopt( $curl_handle, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );
});
```

Or you can [download the same solution as a plugin I made](https://cleverstart.cz/downloads/oprava-vkladani-videi-ve-wordpress-sablone-divi/) - the site is in Czech Language, but it will lead to downloading very simple plugin doing the same thing